# <span> changing layout of website even though position is absolute?

Tags: css, styles, css-position, html

Here is my code. 
The HTML:

```
<div class=column1of4>
<a rel="Appendix" href="images/watermarks/watermark_pic1.jpg" title="Bottle in the   mirror"><img src="images/250-width/pic1.jpg" alt="" width="250px" height="250px"     id="Bottleinthemirrorpic"></a>
<span id="Bottleinthemirror" class="spanlink"><p>Bottle in the mirror<p></span>
</div>

<div class=column1of4>
<a rel="Appendix" href="images/watermarks/watermark_pic9.jpg" title="The empty glass"><img src="images/250-width/pic9.jpg" alt="" width="250px" height="250px"></a>
</div>

<div class=column1of4>
<a rel="Appendix" href="images/watermarks/watermark_pic10.jpg" title="The last drop"><img src="images/250-width/pic10.jpg" alt="" width="250px" height="250px"></a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#Bottleinthemirror {
    width: 250px;
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.55);
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.column1of4 {
    margin: 50px;
    float: left;    
}
```

The Javascript:

```
$('#Bottleinthemirror').hide();
$('#Bottleinthemirrorpic, #Bottleinthemirror').hover(function(){
 //in
  $('#Bottleinthemirror').show();

},function(){
 //out
 $('#Bottleinthemirror').hide();
});
```

Basically, I have three pictures, two of them beside each other and the third one is below the first one. Which I hover over the first picture, I want the #bottleinthemirror span to appear, which it does. The problem is, even when the span is hidden, it still rearranges the layout of the website and moves the picture below it to another place even though it's position is set to absolute. Any idea why? When I remove the span, the website layout is normal. It changes when I put in the span even though the spans position is absolute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the problem is that `span` can not contain `p`, and in your code there are technically 2 `p` elements in the `span` (both `p` tags are opening). When browsers fix this incorrect markup, part of the last `p` may appear outside the `span`. If there is a need to have `p` inside `.spanlink`, it's better to use `div` instead of `span`. But is the `p` really necessary here?

Comment: Figure/figcaption might be a better choice here.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. And no the p wasn't necessary, I just had it because I wanted to change the css for the text inside the <span> or <div>, so I made it <p> so that I can do .spanlink p {css}.. but your "closing the p tag" solution fixed the error.. On a side note, is there a way to target the text inside a <div> or <span> when there is no tag for the text? So if it was <div>text</div> how would I be able to target and add padding to text?

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS selectors can target only DOM elements or, at least, their parts (e.g. 1st letter or 1st line), not just text. But you can add padding to the `div` itself, or add pseudo-elements to take the space.

Answer (score 0):

I set this up in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r2XG2/1/ and it appears to be working for me in Chrome. What browser are you in? I would try the following if it's still not working for you:

Set `z-index: 100` to see if that will force it to appear over the other elements. You could also try setting the `top` or `left` values in css, that may also force it to appear in the correct place. Adding `display: block;` couldn't hurt either.

Edit: Updated fiddle with latest update from asker it also appears that IE won't load jsfiddle. I added `position: relative` to the parent div to see if that helps.

```
#Bottleinthemirror {
    width: 250px;
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.55);
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
}

.column1of4 {
    margin: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: z-index of #bottleinthemirror? I tried that, it didn't make a change for some reason. I'm on Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add the .column1of4 CSS, I just added it, can you look at the code again? Sorry about that

Comment: Updated answer, take a look. One of those things I suggest should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display: block;
```

to

```
#Bottleinthemirror
```